# ASP.Net Core 3.1 on IIS 8.5 - 404 error on default route

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8

I've published an ASP.Net Core 3.1 app to my IIS 8.5 web server (Win 2012 R2).  I installed the Core hosting bundle 3.1.14 and Web Deploy 3.6.  The AppPool is set to No Managed Code and Integrated. I can deploy without error but the web site (xxx.yyy.com) shows up as just the IIS 7 welcome page.  If I try to access the web site with the controller and view (xxx.yyy.com/home/index) I get a 404.  It is working correctly on my local machine on IISExpress.

Here is my startup.cs:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "__RequestVerificationToken");
            services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            services.AddSession();

            services.Configure<FormOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ValueCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Shared/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("IntranetAnnouncements", "IntranetAnnouncements", "IntranetAnnouncements/{controller=IntranetAnnouncements}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("EmployeeBirthdays", "IntranetAnnouncements", "IntranetAnnouncements/{controller=EmployeeBirthdays}/{action=Index}/{month}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("EmployeeYearsOfService", "IntranetAnnouncements", "IntranetAnnouncements/{controller=EmployeeYearsOfService}/{action=Index}/{month}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("Reports", "Reports", "Reports/{controller=Reports}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("SalesStartsCloses", "Reports", "Reports/{controller=SalesStartsCloses}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("CommissionsPaidPerJob", "Reports", "Reports/{controller=CommissionsPaidPerJob}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("BondTableOfContents", "Reports", "Reports/{controller=BondTableOfContents}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("ActivityBySubdivision", "Reports", "Reports/{controller=ActivityBySubdivision}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("Bonds", "Bonds", "Bonds/{controller=Bonds}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("ProjectMaintenance", "Bonds", "Bonds/{controller=ProjectMaintenance}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("Commissions", "Commissions", "Commissions/{controller=Commissions}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("ModelSearch", "ModelSearch", "ModelSearch/{controller=ModelSearch}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("PropertyManagement", "PropertyManagement", "PropertyManagement/{controller=PropertyManagement}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("PropertySearch", "PropertySearch", "PropertySearch/{controller=PropertySearch}/{action=Index}");
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute("PurchaseOrderSearch", "PurchaseOrderSearch", "PurchaseOrderSearch/{controller=PurchaseOrderSearch}/{action=Index}");
            });
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?  Thank you!

EDIT:  Attached a screenshot of the error...just a standard 404.

[image: Error]

EDIT:  Here is a screenshot of our IIS.  The site is published as its own site, not under the default web site.

[image: IIS]

Here is a screenshot of the physical path defined in IIS.

[image: Physical Path]

Finally, here is a screenshot of Windows Explorer showing that the code is indeed located in the same spot as the physical path defined in IIS.

[image: Windows Explorer]

Comment: Have you set a default document? Can you post a detailed screenshot of the error page?

Comment: It's an MVC app so no default document should need to be set.  I've added the screenshot above...just a standard 404.

Comment: Since your root route goes to default welcome page, I am pretty sure that site points to the wrong physical path. Look in IIS basic settings - Physical path

Comment: @Felix, Thank you but no, the physical path is indeed correct in IIS basic settings.

Comment: If it were correct, it wouldn't show welcome page

Comment: Could you please tell me you have published asp.net core application into the default web site or not?Or you created a new web site?  If possible, please post the image of related iis site makeup in your IIS management console.

Comment: I've attached screenshots above.